# Android internal memory path

Tags: java, android

I have a file in the internal memory of my Android tablet and I need the path to that file for an application, but I do not know how to get the exact path of the file.

Comment: Do "you" have the file as a user or as a developer?  If as a developer, the `File` object has methods to give its full path.  If as a user, you will have to first figure out how to access the file using either someone else's informative code, or your own code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply pass the file path if it is located in your app's private storage. The problem is, the other application does not have permissions to read the app, and thus would fail while trying.

You'll have to implement a [`ContentProvider`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html), or more specificly, a [`FileProvider`.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html)

Comment: While true, it is possible the question is for passing a path to some library. In which case, getting the `File` object pointing to the file on internal storage (using `getFilesDir()` or `getCacheDir()`, wherever the file was saved) can give you the path (via `getAbsolutePath()` on the `File`).

Comment: I should be able to open files that have been copied to the tablet (the same place) but I do not know the exact path to the location where the files are copied.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question asked.  If you want to raise an additional concern, do so in a comment, or in addition to answering the question which was actually asked.  Finally, note that your premise is mistaken as files in the private storage are not mandatorily private, although that *may be the default* creation mode for them.

Comment: sorry but my English skills are limited